# A single-line text editor with procedural formatting in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, rich-text-editor

I need to let user to enter a series of identifiers in a input box on my web-page.

For example: `trains cars planes`.

If user enters an identifier that I recognize, I need to render an icon to the left of it, and change the formatting of an identifier (font-weight, color, background color, corner radius, padding etc.).

For example: `[fa-train]trains [fa-car]cars [fa-plane]planes`.

The widget must automatically adjust its height to fit the text if it becomes too long to fit.

User should not be able to directly change the formatting of the text in any way, or, say remove an icon. If user copies or pastes the text, only plain text is to be copied or pasted, without information about icons.

Is there an easy way to implement this widget?

Comment: You can take a look at the code for this angular-emoji filter. Seems like you'll need to watch the input for changes and do some sort of regex to an array. https://github.com/dbaq/angular-emoji-filter-hd

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the [Tagit](https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-tagit) program that stack overflow uses. I believe you can add your own HTML markup into the array list. This should solve your icon problems.

Comment: It does not behave as an edit control would by default — and I can't find any docs on how to make it behave as it does on SO.

Comment: i didn't get what you want in your comment, do want to use Tag-it in something like a TextArea instead of a simple input?

Answer (score -3):

You can easily create an inline rich text editor by using `contenteditable` property and some imagination.

Just click on the dashed div an write a period '.' at the end of the sentence.

```js
$('#editor').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  //alert($('#editor').html);
  var texto = $('#editor').html();
  var pos = texto.search('perro');
  if (pos != -1) {
    //alert('perro hallado en '+pos);
    var tam = 5;
    var inicio = texto.slice(0, pos);
    var urlperro = "http://cdns2.freepik.com/foto-gratis/_318-57958.jpg";
    var fin = texto.slice(pos + tam, texto.length);
    $('#editor').html(inicio + '<img src="' + urlperro + '" width="35">' + fin);
  }
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border=1px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Custom HTML5 inline rich text editor</h1>
<h2>Instructions</h2>
<p>Try editing the text inside the dashed container it will replace some special combination of characters to rich text in html format.</p>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Tengo un pequeño perro que vive conmigo</div>
```

Comment: I think the asker wanted to add the identifier/image before the text, not in place of it. You could do this by adding the string you split on (`'perro'` in this case) after the `<img>` tag (so `inicio + '<img ... > perro' + fin` in this case)

Comment: `$('#editor').html(inicio + '<img src="' + urlperro+'fa-perro' + '" width="35">' + fin);`

Comment: Doesn't that add `'perro'` into the image source attribute?

Comment: And yes.. we had to add a hidden field or something like that with the purpose of register if it was parsed, to unparse and parse on every domchange... but you can get the idea with the snippet.

Comment: woops you r right my mistake: `$('#editor').html(inicio + '<img src="' + urlperro+ '" width="35" />'+'<p>fa-perro</p>'  + fin);`